# Laravel Livewire File Upload return Null

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am having an issue with livewire on uploading files. I am using a very basic example to achieve my goal but the issue is that it returns null on Submit.

Here is my Livewire controller Code:

```
class UploadPhoto extends Component

{

    use WithFileUploads;

 

    public $photo;

 

    public function save()

    {

        dd($this->photo); //returns null

        $this->validate([

            'photo' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max

        ]);

 

        $this->photo->store('photos');

    }

}

        

            

<form wire:submit.prevent="save">

    <input type="file" wire:model="photo">

 

    @error('photo') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

 

    <button type="submit">Save Photo</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Livewire 1.2.0 or higher?

Comment: Yes i am using 2.0

Comment: If you treat Livewire form as a normal form it is wrong, the livewire state is different with Laravel, you can't access livewire properties on form summation

Comment: Elaborate a bit with example. Because given example is almost same as given on livewire docs

Comment: IDK why there isn't a fair Answer to this... I've been having the exact same problem for a few days now. Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

So, as I said before, I also had the same issue a few weeks ago.

I had a very basic **Livewire Controller** to Store an image, but no matter what I did the input kept returning a **NULL** value or kept saying that the image input was **REQUIRED** even if the image was selected.

But, if I used a regular Controller (no Livewire) everything worked perfectly somehow.

After wasting many hours, I still launched my site on production and noticed that everything worked like a charm in there.

So I kept wondering: **Why is it NOT WORKING in my LOCAL environment?**

Everything was up-to-date !

I was also running my project locally and had been working with a Hot Reload served on the Port :3000 (http://localhost:3000).

As the issue was driving me crazy, I **stopped the Hot Reload** and continued testing everything on the main served hostname (localhost).

And **magically**... everything worked.

I still don't understand why Livewire ain't working properly with a Hot Reload. I mean, everything works like it should except for the `input type="file"` to **store an image**.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Stopping hot reload fixes things. thanks a lot bro.  you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

you sure use withFileUploads?

`use Livewire\WithFileUploads;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer "as is" is not helpful, I think you could elaborate a little more on the topic or link to another answer in order to help the OP

Answer (score 0):

Your code block seems to be ok but there is one missing tag to prevent update element. For that we use wire:ignore.self. wire:ignore.self will inform livewire to don't update this element or it's children".

Here is the correct code for your example:

```html
class UploadPhoto extends Component

{

    use WithFileUploads;

 

    public $photo;

 

    public function save()

    {

        dd($this->photo); //returns null

        $this->validate([

            'photo' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max

        ]);

 

        $this->photo->store('photos');

    }

}

        

            
<div wire:ignore.self>
  <form wire:submit.prevent="save">

      <input type="file" wire:model="photo">



      @error('photo') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror



      <button type="submit">Save Photo</button>

  </form>
</div>
```